# If the earth was really massive, then is it possible that no sunlight will reach earth due to gravitational lensing?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, gravitational-lensing

Say the earth was really massive, that it warps space significantly then is it possible that no sunlight will reach earth due to gravitational lensing?

Comment: Gravitational lensing happens when a body **attracts** light (light "bends inwards"). If the earth was more massive, it would attract more light, not less...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravitational lensing by a dense object:
[image: Picture depicting gravitational lensing]

Earth would receive even more light if it were more massive because an increase in the strength of earth's gravitational field would mean that earth attracts even more light than it did with it's normal gravitational field. Gravitational lensing only deflects the path of distant objects which makes them appear distorted and it deflects the path of light in such a way that light is attracted towards the dense object rather than being repelled away from it.

---

Even if you were to place a black hole of mass equal to earth's mass in earth's place, it would still continue to receive sunlight from the sun.

Comment: instead of a star or galaxy, if the light source was something which emits only one photon, then what will happen?

Comment: If the photon source is directed towards the earth, the photons from the source would surely reach the earth and would not suffer any deflection due to earth's gravitational field that would send them away from the planet instead of towards it.